# Converting Complex-Valued Angles from Radians to Degrees in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

After using cmath to compute the asin of 1.47, which returns a complex angle measured in radians;

> cmath.asin(1.47)
>
> (1.5707963267948966+0.9350931316301407j)

Is there a way in which can I convert this value to degrees? math.degrees does not work since it cannot compute with complex values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Degrees make little sense in complex numbers. But if you must use them, just use the same math formula as for real numbers:

```
cmath.asin(1.47) * 180 / math.pi
```

You get the result

```
(90+53.576889894078214j)
```

Note the 90 degrees in the real part.

The usefulness of this depends on the context. For example, when taking a complex logarithm, only the imaginary part of the result is an angle and thus can be expressed in degrees. The real part is the logarithm of the modulus of the parameter and has nothing to do with an angle. In that case, use the above conversion only on the imaginary part. In your arcsine example, usually only the real part is considered an angle, which is why you got the simple `90` for the real part but a mess for the imaginary part.

Let us know just what you are doing with this and we can help you determine the best way to use degrees.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What I am doing can be summarized as follows;

1). Simulating a Kolmogorov Phase Screen of refractive indices to simulate ionospheric interference on incoming radiowaves of cosmic origin.

2). Converting the refractive indices to refracted degrees using Snell's Law; n1sin(theta1)=n2sin(theta2)

Where n1 is 1, theta1 is 90 degrees and n2 is the refractive index as given through the Kolmogorov Phase screen. 

By taking the arcsin of (n1sin(theta1))/n2, theta2 can be calculated. theta2 is required as input in degrees for a radio interferometer simulation.

Comment: The issue with the above calculation is that n2 is actually smaller than 1, meaning that (n1sin(theta1))/n2 adds up to be always larger than 1. With this value larger than 1, the arcsin will always result in a negative value.

Of course the Kolmogorov Phase Screen refractive indices could be erroneous here, requiring their values to be actually larger than 1. However, the interferometric simulation software documentation does indicate that degree offsets should be complex, so I cannot discount this possibility either.

Comment: I meant "the arcsin wll always result in a complex value" not a "negative value"

Comment: In what I have seen of Snell's law, if the sine of the desired angle is greater than 1 that means that there is no refraction and only reflection takes place. This is what causes [total internal reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection). Consider that may be what is happening in your simulation: no refraction.

Answer (score 0):

To use math.degrees(), you need to get the real part of the complex number first.

```
import cmath
import math
rad = cmath.asin( 1.47 )
math.degrees( rad.real )
```